# Error Message: "through traffic restriction might apply" (Here Maps Fleet Telematics API)

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

When using Fleet Telematics API I have been getting the error message quite often -- about 10% of the routes I want to calculate: "Couldn't reach way point 1 (start links 781909352 -781909352  dest links 881144574 -881144574 881144579 -881144579 ), link 881144574's through traffic restriction might apply, link 881144579's through traffic restriction might apply"

Sample query: http://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&driver_cost=20&currency=EUR&rollups=total,country,tollsys,country;tollsys&commercial=1&shippedHazardousGoods=0&waypoint0=52.51,13.42&waypoint1=45.747353, 11.733903&tollVehicleType=3&vehicle_cost=0.5&fuelType=Diesel&emissionType=6&length=1500cm&height=270cm&heightAbove1stAxle=120cm&vehicleWeight=7000kg&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&trailerNumberAxles=4&trailerHeight=270cm

What are these numbers after the word "links"? Do they give more information about what the restriction might be? And if so, how do I access that information?

When I manually adjust the waypoint latitude and longitude a bit to move it to a nearby bigger road, a route is able to be found. But for me this needs to be automated to work. If I could increase the radius around the waypoint that would be considered a "success" to find a route, that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers after the word "links' are link IDs with the `-` indicating an opposite direction of travel. The error means the algorithm cannot get a valid route that goes through those two waypoints without violating the restrictions that you have provided (as parameters). You can add a `routeMatch` parameter with value `1` so the algorithm will treat you waypoints as GPS trace and find the most probable trace along the route.